# Did I just screw up my paint, or is it just dried polish?

Tags: paint, polishing

I have some pretty jacked up looking paint on the roof of my 2000 Honda Civic, and decided I would try to hand polish it a little.  So I got out a very soft white hex logic pad, and some extra fine polish ( real polish ), cleaned a small area on the roof and went at it.  It's very hot were I live, so I tried to make sure to polish for just a few seconds and then wipe off any excess polish.  I was also using a bit of Optimum No Rinse to moisten everything up.

Well when I wiped away the excess polish I was shocked to see a light dull whiteness seemingly covering my dark navy blue roof.  So I went later in the day and got a Nanoskin pad to try and take it off, without much success as can be seen below.  I also used the pad to scrub down that whole same side of the roof ( which I had not polished ).

Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

You can see on the right side that the street lamp is reflecting on the roof where I used the nanoskin pad, yet the spot where I polished has a distint whitish appearance. You can see in this pick of the left side what it looked like before and how the lamp doesn't reflect almost at all:

[image]

Anyways, am I up a creek, or do I have some hope that this is just dried polish that I can somehow remove?

**EDIT**

Just to make it more clear, I'm talking about actual abrasive polish, not wax.

This is the product I was using, [IMPA Phase 1 Rubbing Cream](http://www.impa.it/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=837&virtuemart_category_id=382&lang=en).

Comment: Do you have any products like [Prep-All](http://www.autobodytoolmart.com/klean-strip-prep-all-wax-grease-remover-p-14855.aspx) in your neck of the woods? This should take it off, but I'm worried about the heat there which may still cause you issues.

Comment: Not sure.  There's really only one shop in my city that carries auto paint supplies.  Regarding the heat, I can just do it early in the morning or late at night.  How about using IPA?

Comment: Not sure, but possibly. Really, as it stands, you have nothing to lose, right? I don't think IPA will bring it off, though. The Prep-All can be found at most stores like Walmart here. I don't know what you have there. It would do the best job of getting it off, though. Yah, whatever you do, do it as early in the morning as possible. If the paint is completely cool (or at least at a reasonable temp), you may even try more wax and see if that would do the trick ... I really don't know, though.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 But you're pretty sure that's just dried on polish?  I mean actual abrasive polish, it's not wax.

Comment: You haven't polished you lacquer (clear coat) off, have you?

Comment: @HandyHowie I have no idea.  I hope not, but I've never done this before.  I wouldn't think that 10 or 15 seconds of hand polishing would take me down to primer....

Comment: It wouldn't take you down to primer, just the coloured paint layer.  When you say polish, do you mean a cutting compound?

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes, I just edited the post with a link to the specific compound I used.

Comment: I'm finding allot of people on forums recommending peanut butter.  That sounds strange.

Comment: If this panel has been resprayed there is a good chance that it's now single-stage paint (ie no clearcoat). If so,  chances are that the whitening is the result of a chemical reaction. Not looking good.

Comment: The [data sheet](http://www.impa.it/images/stories/virtuemart/product/en/2204.pdf) indicates that it is meant to be used on "hardened varnish" surfaces (clearcoat). It also says that the product is designed to remove overspray. Judging by your results I'd say it achieves this through chemical attack, not abrasion.

Comment: @Zaid I'm pretty sure it's original paint on the top.  I can see where the clear is starting to come up at the edge on the other side.  It just seems like the roof paint has been baked over the years and gotten tons of little micro abrasions.  I've got some 95% IPA I'm going to go out and try now on a small spot.

Comment: @Zaid I tried some IPA, alternating between that and the nanoskin with optimum no rinse, and that seemed to be pulling up a little of it, but I think it would take 10 hours to get it all off.  Reading the back of the bottle, it says it's for removing light scratches and micro-abrassions, which makes me think it's got a mild abrassive in it.  I saw this Polish: Quick Off on the same companies website so maybe I'll see if they carry it around here and try it:  http://www.impa.it/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=838&virtuemart_category_id=382&lang=en